# UFW blocks connections that should be enabled

Tags: server, iptables, firewall, ufw

It turns out that at certain times when certain users try to connect, UFW automatically rejects the connection, preventing them from being loaded by the server, even marking them as disconnected. This happens to me with port 25565/tcp which is open in UFW.
I don't understand what could cause it, that UFW suddenly rejects connections to a port that is supposed to be open to receive them.
Doing a little research on the ufw logs I found the rejections:
https://hastebin.com/nivefoxefo.rb

And when placing iptables -L -v I found these rule lines, which obviously have something to do because both of them point out that when a block occurs they must log [UFW BLOCK], that is, what is seen in the logs.

[see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyvDY.png)

Any solution that you recommend?
(I already uninstalled and reinstalled ufw, and put iptables --flush)

The iptables -L -n -v --line-numbers : https://hastebin.com/ubemunuler.bash
The ufw status verbose : https://hastebin.com/efibeyoyiz.makefile

Comment: The two 'ufw' rules you're showing us are only because of the *log* lines.  Can you post the **entire** output of `iptables -L -n -v --line-numbers` into your question as an edit please?  We need to see the rules in place here to really understand what's going on.  And if you've already flushed your rules, then you should be able to confirm that you don't have any rules in place, at all, in `iptables` or `ufw` currently)  Also include the output of `ufw status verbose` please as an edit too.

Comment: He had effectively cleared the rules of iptables. But after restarting my ubuntu server they were rebuilt.
So in the post I will put the two links with what you asked me. Thanks if you can help me. @ThomasWard

Comment: as you said you *reinstalled* `ufw`.  That will reactivate the stored rulesets, unless you did `sudo apt purge ufw` which also removes the configurations.  UFW might not be rejecting the connections, rather you might not have a service listening on the port on the system when you're testing.  Double check your service is actually listening (`sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 25565`)

Comment: By placing what you asked me I get these results https://hastebin.com/kuxiveciwo.rb it seems that if it is being heard. What do you recommend me to do now then? @ThomasWard

Comment: For port 25565 you are only listening to ipv6 protocol.